# Array will not read new value for column

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java so the answer might be obvious, but I'm having difficulty trying to get my code to display only the inputted rows entered by the user with custom columns on each row. I have attempted to find similar issue as mine but i could not find cases similar to mine.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayIrreg {

private static Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

char group, rLetter;
//int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num = 10; // for test
int rows=10;
int columns = 8;

// creating 2d array
double[][] figures = new double[rows][num];

    System.out.print("Please enter number of rows               : ");
    rows = Keyboard.nextInt();

    while(rows<0||rows>=10){
        System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
            rows = Keyboard.nextInt();
   }

for(int t=0;t<rows;t++){
       rLetter = (char)((t)+(int)'A'); 
       System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row "+rLetter+" : ");
            columns= Keyboard.nextInt();

        while(columns<0||columns>=8) {
              System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
                  columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
              }

        for(int j=0;j<=columns;j++) {                     
                  figures[t] = new double[j] ;
        }         

     }
// filling the array
for(int row=0; row<figures.length; ++row) {
    for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {
        figures[row][col] = 0.0; 
    }
}

// printing the array
for(int row=0; row<figures.length; ++row) {

    // printing data row
    group = (char)((row)+(int)'A');
    System.out.print(group+" : ");
    for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {

        System.out.print(figures[row][col] + " ");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

// printing final border
for(int col=0; col<figures[0].length; ++col) {
    System.out.print(" -");
}

System.out.println("  ");
}
}
```

When 3 is enter for rows and 1,2,3 is entered for columns, the code prints:

```
   A:0.0  
   B:0.0 0.0
   C:0.0 0.0 0.0
   D:0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   F:0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   G:0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   H:0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   J:0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

But I only want this to be displayed:

```
A:0.0  
B:0.0 0.0
C:0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is always initialize `figures` array with `10` rows, you need to move the declaration of the array after the user input like this:

```
System.out.print("Please enter number of rows               : ");
    rows = Keyboard.nextInt();

    // creating 2d array
    double[][] figures = new double[rows][num];
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize *figures* in the beginning of main method with

```
    double[][] figures = new double[rows][num];
```

which translates to

```
    double[][] figures = new double[10][10];
```

You should instead acquire rows and num first dynamically and then initialise figures. As a quick fix you can also iterate your row loops rows times

```
    for(int row=0; row<rows; ++row) {
```

but the downside is that if number of rows is bigger than 10 the figures initialisation would probably cause index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char group, rLetter;
//int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int num = 10; // for test
    int rows=10;
    int columns = 8;

// creating 2d array


    System.out.print("Please enter number of rows               : ");
    rows = Keyboard.nextInt();

    if(rows<0||rows>=10){
        System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
        rows = Keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    double[][] figures = new double[rows + 1][num];
    for(int t=0;t<rows;t++){
        rLetter = (char)((t)+(int)'A');
        System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row "+rLetter+" : ");
        columns= Keyboard.nextInt();

        if(columns<0||columns>=8) {
            System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
            columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        for(int j=0;j<=columns;j++) {
            figures[j] = new double[j] ;
        }

    }
// filling the array
    for(int row=0; row<figures.length; ++row) {
        for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {
            figures[row][col] = 0.0;
        }
    }

// printing the array
    for(int row=0; row<figures.length; ++row) {

        // printing data row
        group = (char)((row)+(int)'A');
        System.out.print(group+" : ");
        for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {

            System.out.print(figures[row][col] + " ");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

// printing final border
    for(int col=0; col<figures[0].length; ++col) {
        System.out.print(" -");
    }

    System.out.println("  ");
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: But the code skips up a line for some reason and leaves row A blank before printing in B C and D when 1 2 3 are entered in as column values.